# Pthread not getting expected argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, pthreads

Here's a simple C++ code snippet that creates 2 pthread.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int ID);
    int get_id() {return id;}
private:
    int id;
};

A::A(int ID): id(ID) {}


void* basic_function( void* arg)
{
    A *ptr = static_cast<A*>(arg);
    printf("A passed in with id %d\n", ptr->get_id());
}

int main()
{
    vector<pthread_t> thread_vec;
    vector<A> A_vec;

    for (int i=0; i< 2; ++i)
    {
        A_vec.push_back(A(i));

        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, basic_function, (void*)(&(A_vec[i])));
        thread_vec.push_back(tid);
    }

    void * ret;
    for (auto i: thread_vec)
        pthread_join(i, &ret);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that `basic_function` would print

```
A passed in with id 0
A passed in with id 1
```

But instead what I got is

```
A passed in with id -1804310784
A passed in with id 1
```

Looks like there's a race condition. Bu I'm using `A_vec` to hold input data for different iterations, so I guess the data is independent and does not interfere with each other. What might be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Does doing an A_vec.reserve(2) before your first for-loop help?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes it helps, can you please explain why?

Comment: When a vector increases its capacity (like what can happen when you add elements to it) then is might *reallocate* the contents of the vector. That will make all pointers and iterators to elements in the vector invalid. Better pass (a reference to) the vector itself together with the vector index. This becomes *very* easy if you stop using the lower-level POSIX threads and instead use the C++ [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) class.